# Why is explicitly annotating the lifetime required in the first case, but not in the second?

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime

Here, the annotating `'a` explicitly for `items` is required:

```rust
struct App<'a> {
    items: StatefulList<'a, (&'a str, &'a str, usize)>,
}

impl<'a> App<'a> {
    fn new(items: &'a Vec<(&'a str, &'a str, usize)>) -> App<'a> {
        App {
            items: StatefulList::with_items(items),
        }
    }
}
```

However, here it is not:

```rust
struct StatefulList<'a, T> {
    state: ListState,
    items: &'a Vec<T>,
}

impl<'a, T> StatefulList<'a, T> {
    fn with_items(items: &Vec<T>) -> StatefulList<T> {
        StatefulList {
            state: ListState::default(),
            items,
        }
    }
}
```

Why is that?

For now, I think it is because the compiler can't figure out the lifetime in the first case.

Comment: Do not post text as images. Also, format your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this litte thing:

```rust
fn with_items(items: &Vec<T>) -> StatefulList<T> {
//                                           ^ here, where did the lifetime go?
```

`StatefulList` is declared with a lifetime. But you omitted the lifetime! What is the lifetime when you omit it?

It is the elided lifetime, `'_`, or the "figure it out" lifetime. And the compiler "figures it out" via simple [liftime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html). And part of these rules is that when there is only one lifetime in the parameters (like in this case - the implicit lifetime of the `items: &Vec<T>`), the lifetimes in the return type all inhreit it. So written explicitly, the signature is:

```rust
fn with_items<'b>(items: &'b Vec<T>) -> StatefulList<'b, T>
```

The `'a` lifetime from the `impl` block *is not used at all*. The returned `StatefulList` has the same lifetime as the parameter - which is excellent, because you use the parameter for its `items`!

In the first case, on the other hand, we explicitly specify the `'a` lifetime from the `impl` block. You still use the parameter, and so the parameter's lifetime has to match - and it has to be `'a` too.

There is a lint that will help you avoid that situation: it is called [`elided_lifetimes_in_paths`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/allowed-by-default.html#elided-lifetimes-in-paths), and is part of the `rust_2018_idioms` lints group which I strongly recommend `#![forbid]`ing for new projects. If you will do that, the compiler will complain:

```rust
error: hidden lifetime parameters in types are deprecated
  --> src/lib.rs:12:51
   |
12 |     fn with_items(items: &Vec<T>) -> StatefulList<T> {
   |                                                   ^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
note: the lint level is defined here
  --> src/lib.rs:1:11
   |
1  | #![forbid(rust_2018_idioms)]
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: `#[forbid(elided_lifetimes_in_paths)]` implied by `#[forbid(rust_2018_idioms)]`
help: consider using the `'_` lifetime
   |
12 |     fn with_items(items: &Vec<T>) -> StatefulList<'_, T> {
   |                                                   +++
```

Comment: Thanks.It helps me clear up a confusion

Comment: another confusion .```fn new(items: &  Vec<(&str,&str, usize)>) -> App``` why can't I remove all the 'a ,use the liftime elision rules.

Comment: ```fn new<'b>(items: & 'b Vec<(&str,&str, usize)>) -> App<'b>```I try this and also work.But it seems that it can elided.

Comment: @cowboybebop It is quite complicated. Too long to explain in a comment. This is related to the lifetime elision rules. You can ask a new question.

Comment: thanks.mybe I can edit the question, cause the final confusion is about the explicitly lifetime annotate on the **new**method,but not need on **with_items** method

Comment: @cowboybebop DO NOT edit a question to ask a new or additional question. Ask a new question. I've rolled your edit back.

Comment: ok I post a new one. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72477610/why-is-explicitly-annotating-the-lifetime-required-in-the-first-case-on-the-meth)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that in the second one you do not return anything that has to deal with lifetimes, but an owned version of `StatefulList`. In the first one it need to match the lifetime to what you are returning, to ensure that the data you return may live enough.

In fact you don't even need some of the annotations, since the compiler will coerce the lifetime for you.

```rust
impl<'a> App<'a> {
    fn new(items: &'a Vec<(&str, &str, usize)>) -> App<'a> {
        App {
            items: StatefulList::with_items(items),
        }
    }
}
```

`&str` need to live at least as much as `&'a Vec`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4dfa2937b92867acfe069f454a9df1cb)

Comment: hi I edit the question for anthor confusion.Maybe you can help  figure it out.Thanks anyway.