# Why can I elide the lifetime of the return type in one case but another one requires to choose a lifetime explicitly?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Here, I must give `App` a full lifetime and cannot elide it (`App<'_>`):

```rust
struct App<'a> {
    items: StatefulList<'a, (&'a str, &'a str, usize)>,
}

impl App<'_> {
    fn new<'a>(items: &'a Vec<(&'a str, &'a str, usize)>) -> App<'a> {
        App {
            items: StatefulList::with_items(items),
        }
    }
}
```

It also works if I only specify the lifetime for the outer `Vec`:

```rust
fn new<'a>(items: &'a Vec<(&str, &str, usize)>) -> App<'a>
```

If I try to elide it, it gives ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eb227efdf27ab50f08e77eeb83cb8627)):

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/lib.rs:18:53
   |
18 |     fn new(items: &Vec<(&str, &str, usize)>) -> App<'_> {
   |                   -------------------------         ^^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the signature does not say which one of `items`'s 3 lifetimes it is borrowed from
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
   |
18 |     fn new<'a>(items: &'a Vec<(&str, &str, usize)>) -> App<'a> {
   |           ++++         ++                                  ~~
```

However, here for `with_items` method I can happily elide the lifetime:

```rust
struct StatefulList<'a, T> {
    state: ListState,
    items: &'a Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> StatefulList<'_, T> {
    fn with_items(items: &Vec<T>) -> StatefulList<'_, T> {
        StatefulList {
            state: ListState::default(),
            items,
        }
    }
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Because lifetime elision rules only work if there is a single lifetime among the function parameters.

Comment: @Jmb.sorry, I don't understand the meaning of the ```a single lifetime among the function parameters```.Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: The first `new()` potentially has three lifetime parameters. If you don't explicitly specify the lifetimes, each of the three `'a` you wrote in the parameter list will be considered a different lifetime. In the second case, there's only a single lifetime parameter in the argument list, so [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#lifetime-elision-in-functions) apply.

Comment: Do not copy-paste an old question and include a new one. Adjust your code to ask only one question, preferably with a minimal example and not your original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you why:

> this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the signature does not say which one of `items`'s 3 lifetimes it is borrowed from

There are *three* lifetimes in the type `&Vec<(&str, &str, usize)>`: `&'a Vec<(&'b str, &'c str, usize)>`. The [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) can only choose the lifetime for the return type when there is *one* parameter, or if there is a `self` parameter in which case they uses its lifetime.

Comment: Thanks I thought ```&Vec<(&str, &str, usize)>``` they combine together as one parameter.So when I specify ```& 'a Vec<T>```, every reference in Vec would has a lifetime longer than ```'a```. Than I can elide the lifetime in the Vec.

Comment: @cowboybebop It's true that when you specify `&'a Vec<T>` every lifetime in `T` will be >= `'a`, but that is because implied bounds, not because elision.

Comment: implied bounds.is it a default rule when use vec<T> in rust ?

Comment: @cowboybebop [implied bounds](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2089-implied-bounds.html) is what causes `&'a T` to have an implicit bound `T: 'a`, and followingly, `&'a &'b T` to have a bound `'b: 'a`. `&'a Vec<T>` also has a bound `T: 'a`.